# Trouble communicating between docker containers

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I'm running an "elasticsearch" container.  I can curl the container and get results but when I try to communicate with the container from within my "web" container it refuses the connection.

```
docker-compose up
curl localhost:9200 // works.
curl docker-compose run web curl localhost:9200 // connection refused.
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:5.1.2
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.5

ADD . /src
WORKDIR /src

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD python project/wsgi.py
```

Comment: Would you like to add `Dockerfile` too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `localhost:9200` from within the `web` container to connect to the `elasticsearch` container. You could define a link or just use the service name (which is mapped by default):

```
curl elasticsearch:9200
```

> Links allow you to define extra aliases by which a service is reachable from another service. They are not required to enable services to communicate - by default, any service can reach any other service at that service’s name.

Also see [Docker Compose Links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#/links)

Answer (score 1):

You should be trying to curl `elasticsearch:9200`, not `localhost:9200`. The hostname elasticsearch should be in your hosts file on the web container.